# admin modify a user page

Tags: php, html, mysql

i don't know very how to say this but i'll try, let's see, 
i have the page admin.php and the page user.php,
the posibility to log in with specific role for admin exist with:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    // conectare la baza de date
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inregistrare");
    if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
        $password = md5($password); // parola cryptata
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

             if($user['role'] == 'admin'){
            header("location: admin.php");
        }else{
            header("location: clasa.php");
        }

        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Parola gresita!";
        }
    }
?>
```

my problem is i want the users/admins from admin.php to have posibility to edit the user.php to edit something a `<p>`, a `<input>` whatever to apply CSS and the normal user can't edit

Comment: add another session variable like $_SESSION['role']='admin' upon login. On the user.php page, check for the session variable that it is equal to admin. If it is, add the edit button/feature, if not, don't allow

Comment: yes it is, now i need to edit button/feature for edit, and my brain is melted right now so give me some exemples please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your validation:

```
if($user['role'] == 'admin'){
    header("location: admin.php");
}else{
    header("location: clasa.php");
}
```

Add:

```
if($user['role'] == 'admin'){
    $_SESSION['role']='admin';
    header("location: admin.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['role']='user';
    header("location: clasa.php");
}
```

Then in your user.php:

```
if($_SESSION['role']=='admin'){
//add admin features that allow editing
}else{
//add whatever else functions
}
```